# Cannot connect from Express to remote Redis

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I'm having issues with connecting to a remote Redis server. From my local client, when I connect from cli, everything looks fine

```
redis-cli -h 192.168.80.236 ping
PONG
```

If I attempt to connect from a simple Express application, I keep receiving the following error

```
Redis PUBLISHER NodeJS application in port 3000
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1128:14)
Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
    at RedisClient.on_error (/Users/sriramk/Projects/Personal/Express/simpleredis/node_modules/redis/index.js:341:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/sriramk/Projects/Personal/Express/simpleredis/node_modules/redis/index.js:222:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6379
}
```

What baffles me is, Redis connecting to "localhost", when it should really be connecting to remote server. Initially my thought was, may be some auth issues causing the connection problems. But if redis-cli can connect without an hitch, what's the problem with NodeJS
Full code can be found in this location - https://github.com/KrishnanSriram/simpleredis

I'd appreciate you thoughts/advice. I'm totally stopped because of this issue

Comment: `192.168.80.236` is not `127.0.0.1:6379` maybe change your config to `192.168.80.236`

Comment: I had some issues with `redis` library in the past, so I only use `ioredis` nowdays... locally I use docker to host my local Redis instance, and I use it as `const Redis = require('ioredis'); const client = new Redis('redis://127.0.0.1:6379'); ...` give it a try

Comment: @marpme Did you get a chance to look into github code? I don't have 127.0.0.1 in my API. Incase you did not, here's what I have redis.createClient(6379, '192.168.80.236');

Comment: @balexandre That's a good point. I have not tried ioredis, although I read about it. In this case I use Redis for pub/sub. I understand ioredis also supports pub/sub. Need to try and find out how much different ioredis is and how expensive porting will be (from redis to ioredis). Thanks. Much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked out your repo and in your `server.js` I can see that you try to instantiate a redis client twice.

Once with

```
const client = redis.createClient();
```

and then with

```
const publisher = redis.createClient(6379, '192.168.80.236');
```

Removing `const client = redis.createClient();` should fix the issue as this would try to connect to `localhost` on the default port.

Comment: Excellent. Fresh eye always helps. This is why pair programming is great. Thanks for your time. Fixed my issue :)